# get field value of array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the followig:

```
<div class="label">{{ item.data[0] }}</div>
```

and in the view I'm having  the following:

```
{
  "id": 6,
  "firtname": "JHON ",
  "lastname": "SCALA",
  "fullname": "JHON  SCALA"
}
```

I justo want to show fullname

```
<div class="label">{{ item.data[0].fullname }}</div>
```

but I'm having this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fullname')
```

why????

Comment: Is item.data[0] fetched from somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the data is being fetched from database or any other async persistence, vue can't read item.data[0]**.fullname** before its loaded. Try wrapping the div in a v-if like this:

```html
<template v-if="item.data.length > 0">
  <div class="label">{{ item.data[0].fullname }}</div>
</template>
```